# SQL Sub query returns more than one value error

Tags: sql, subquery

What is the issue with insert query below?

I'm trying to insert employee values from one table to another table. But the query gives an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeDetails AS [dbo].[Employee] 
 
INSERT INTO @EmployeeDetails
VALUES ( 101
       )
INSERT INTO @EmployeeDetails
VALUES ( 102
       )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpCopy] (EmpId, Dept)) 
values (
(SELECT EmpId FROM @EmployeeDetails)
,'Sales')
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the message? The subquery returns what? You expected just 1 row why? Or if you expected more than 1 row why did you expect it would work? What DBMS/SQL? [mre] How did the dupicate Q&A for this error not help you? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your post. Please read the editor '?' help & advanced help including re block & inline formats for code & quotes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify the values if you want to insert all the data from another table

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpCopy] (EmpId, Dept)
SELECT EmpId, 'Sales'
FROM @EmployeeDetails
```